# What is the difference between the date queries and which is more efficient?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, index

```
Where tt.transactiondate >= getdate () -1

Where tt.transaciondate >= dateadd (day, -1, getdate())

Where dateadd (day, 1, tt.transactiondate) >= get date()

Where datediff (day, tt.transactiondate, getdate() <= 1
```

What is the difference between the queries?
Which query is more efficient?

Thanks

Comment: Why not test them? Load a sample table with a million rows and time them.

Comment: @lital Rozani, create 4 select statements as per your requirement and try to analyze the execution plans and see if you can see a difference in speed or picking a good plan.

Comment: @Lital Rozani, Just start by that and see if you are hitting any roadblocks then update your question with that. Definitely, someone will come to rescue you.

Comment: @Biju Jose I can do that, but then I'll see what is the difference in speed without knowing why. I need to know the reason :)

Comment: First 2 variants differs in syntax only. But second variant do not allow the ambiguousness in substracted value units. The last 2 variants kills index usage.

Comment: Be sure to try different data types too. Is the transactiondate a date, datetime, varchar or something else? What happens when your parameters match/mismatch the type?

Comment: I vote for the second one - it's working with date using date's function and it's SARGable

Comment: @vonPryz all of them are datetime

Comment: @LitalRozani, No worries, just run the queries, state your findings and paste all 4 actual execution plans in here and ask the question here which you want to know and why I am insisting this is next time when you ran across something like these it will help you to narrow down the problem. Believe me, you will solve the problem yourself next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your queries are not "queries", these are only `where` clauses.

If your question is what is the best way to write a where condition, the answer is

```
Where tt.transaciondate >= dateadd (day, -1, getdate())
```

This is because if there is an index on `transaciondate` it can be used only if your `index key field` (`transaciondate` ) is not inside some function,
i.e. in these cases:

```
Where dateadd (day, 1, tt.transactiondate) >= get date()

Where datediff (day, tt.transactiondate, getdate() <= 1
```

the index on transactiondate (if exists) cannot be used.

The condition written this way

```
Where tt.transactiondate >= getdate () -1
```

is not documented, as you cannot add/subtract `inegers` to `datetime` this way.

The documented way is to use `dateadd()` function.

**UPDATE**

There is already the answer to the question:

> Both queries
>
> ```
> select dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
>
> select GETDATE() - 1
> ```
>
> return the same result which surprises me. The first query is clearly
>   dealing with days and, apparently, the "-1" in the second is
>   interpreted as the number of days too. Where is that conversion
>   feature documented?

given by **Erland Sommarskog** here: [dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) vs. getdate() - 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a41c9399-adac-4b29-8cee-a7f8539d724f/dateaddday1getdate-vs-getdate-1?forum=transactsql)
that I want to replicate here:

> I'm not sure it is documented. In any case, it certainly perfect
>   nonsense.
>
> What happens is this: the expression "`getdate() - 1`" includes two
>   different `data types`. `SQL Server` has a strict `data-type precedence`, and >when two different data types meet in `SQL Server`,
>   the type with lower `precedence` is converted to the other type (or
>   there is an `error` if there is no i`mplicit conversion`).
>
> `int` has lower `precedence` than `datetime`, so `1` gets converted to
>   `1900-01-02`, midnight. Now you have:
>
> ```
> SELECT getdate() - datetime(1900-01-02 00:00:00.000)
> ```
>
> Which logically is of course not very meaningful. But since the
>   underlying representation for `datetime` is a decimal number "it just
>   works".
>
> However, if you try:
>
> ```
> SELECT sysdatetime() - 1
> ```
>
> You get:
>
> > Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1    Operand type clash: datetime2 is
> >     incompatible with int
>
> For the new `date`/`time` data types added in `SQL 2008`, there is no
>   implicit converion from `int`, and there is no addition or subtraction
>   for the values.

Comment: Thanks @sepupic but I still don't understand your last explanation. When I execute both of these clauses they are working and show the same results, so it is possible to add/subtract integers both ways.

Comment: @Lital Rozani, I'll update my answer with the explanation by Erland Sommarskog

Comment: Try the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3cd7b00cd36661f4146833e79c4d13ea  `DATETIME + 1` works, `DATE + 1` and `DATETIME2 + 1` fail.